# Protractor: convert webElement to elementFinder

Tags: protractor

The element.all() returns an array of webelements.  I'd like to be able to further process these elements.  Example would be
element.all(by.something()).each(function(row) {
    var button = row.element(by.buttonWithText("cancel")).then(....

But of course, I can't use row.element because row is a webelement, not an elementFinder.

Is there an easy way of converting a webElement to a elementFinder?

I was thinking of getting the xpath to the webElement then using by.xpath() but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that's ok or you could try something like this

```
ptor.findElements(protractor.By.tag('tr')).then(function(rows){
  rows[0].findElement(protractor.By.linkText('something')).click();
});
```

that should work as you want it to i use this structure in a few places. If you were to use findElement this would work in the same way only it wouldn't be an array so it would be ..rows.findElement..etc

Answer (score 0):

```
element.all()
```

Should return an ElementArrayFinder that you can treat as an Array of ElementFinders, so you should not need to convert it. You have further information in the linke below:

[ElementArrayFinder Documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder)